# WPF TextBox I would like to add a undo / redo like the command prompt when the up and down arrow keys are pushed

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to add the functionality that is found in the command line prompt into my WPF TextBox.  In the command propmpt when the user pushes the up arrow the previous command that was used will appear.  And if he keeps pushing the up arrow the next previous text will be seen.  And if the user pushes down then it will go the other way again.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  (The built in redo / undo works more on a document level than what I am requiring.)

Comment: what do you have tried?

Comment: Do you want it that when you press a button or press enter, it stores whatever is in the textbox as a previous command?

Comment: Have you tried using [Application Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use `InputBindings` to assign `Undo` and `Redo` to appropriate keys?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the undo and redo won't do exactly what I want them to do.  If you open the command prompt and enter a bunch of commands or even gibberish and then you can scroll through the commands you entered with the up and down arrow key...that is what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Undo e Redo Application Commands.
This is the MVVM not compliant version:

**In your XAML**

```
<TextBox Margin="5" PreviewKeyUp="TextBox_PreviewKeyUp" AcceptsReturn="False" />
```

**In your code-behind**

```
private List<string> _history = new List<string>();
private int _historyIndex = -1;

private void TextBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        _history.Add(textBox.Text);
        if (_historyIndex < 0 || _historyIndex == _history.Count - 2)
        {
            _historyIndex = _history.Count - 1;
        }

        textBox.Text = String.Empty;

        return;
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        if (_historyIndex > 0)
        {
            _historyIndex--;
            textBox.Text = _history[_historyIndex];
        }

        return;
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        if (_historyIndex < _history.Count - 1)
        {
            _historyIndex++;
            textBox.Text = _history[_historyIndex];
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

I hope this is the functionality you meant.

Comment: This doesn't work like the command prompt.  In the command prompt you enter a text command and push return.  That whole command that you just typed gets put on a stack and you can scroll through that stack with the up and down arrows.  This code doesn't work like that.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Now I hope it is more suitable to your needs

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing.  Whenever the user hit enter I added another text to the history and if it got to 100 I would erase the last one.  When a new command was entered I then placed the historyIndex to the newest added command.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the PreviewKeyDown event and check for Key.Down or Key.Up and read a List of your last commands. If you set **e.Handled = true** the cursor don't jump up.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        //Here comes the code where you read your last commands and print it to your Textbox
    }

    //Same for Key.Down
}
```

To make it MVVM-compliant you can use an eventtrigger which triggers a command in your Viewmodel.
Hope this gives you the idea. Unfortunately I haven't enough time to program for you. :)

Comment: This is the way I was thinking of doing it.  But I was wondering if I was going to reinvent the wheel if I did it this way.  BTW wouldn't this be code only in the view?  Not the ViewModel?  This seems like something the View should take care of...

Comment: @ashlar64 I think this is a matter of opinion. I prefer to reduce code behind to a minimum.

Comment: Another quick question...is there a reason you picked PreviewKeyDown instead of PreviewKeyUp?

Comment: Because PreviewKeyUp is to late and the Key press is already runned and your cursor is already in the upper line. Try it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can persist commands into stack collection.

Comment: This does *not* qualify as a valid answer, so -1. Please see the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page of the Help Centre for further information.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my distraction I assumed my answer will be converter to the comment.